# De-Reverberator

Tags: reverb

Umm yeah, So I watched this video which was linked from JW sound.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yitJOeFkscc&feature=player_embedded

Very New, Just came out.  But um Wow.

Comment: Looks/sounds ridiculous. 

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the first product to do this on the market. Check out [De-Verb by SPL](http://spl.info/software/microplugs/de-verb.html). User interface is far more minimalist, and it probably has less in the way of fine tuning controls...but it's significantly cheaper.

Comment: Also http://www.dyvision.co.uk/reverbremover.html

Comment: Would love to hear an A,B,C comparison. Do you use De-Verb Shaun?

Comment: @Mviljamaa - interesting, but only VST. :\

Comment: @Mark - I don't, but @ianjpalmer has used De-Verb. He had a blog post on it a while back but I can't seem to find it anymore. Maybe he'll pop in here and let us know what he thinks.

Comment: @Shaun The way it works it completely different from De-Verb.  http://jwsoundgroup.net/index.php?/topic/10986-unveil-unreverberator/ 
is where one of the creators talks and has some words about it.  

Comment: @Michael - I wasn't saying they were the same. Just pointing out to people, who may not be aware, that there are other (albeit less robust) reverberation elimination tools on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. indeed...

Bye / Tumppi

Answer (score 0):

AAX version please

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying the demo version and it's quite amazing.

You need to play around with the controls to get a natural dry sound but sometimes sounds like magic.

Next week I have to work in a quite reverberated scene where I'm going to put it to test.
We'll see!

Answer (score 0):

Looks fantastic.

Shame the full price is going to be €399. There's been a bit of a precedent set that plugins aimed at post are very expensive. It's unfortunate.

Would they sell twice as many at €199? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks unbelievable! Pricey, but there is nothing else like it no?